# Use the template of another django app in an another app

Tags: python, django, templates

I have two django apps. One which belongs to core code and one contrib app. What I need to do is to display a template in my contrib app, which actually exists already in the core app. This is more or less the folder structure:

- django project

  - core app

    - templates
      ...
  - contrib app

    - templates
      -template_from_core_app

The template renders data from views and forms which exist in the core app.  I am wondering what is the best way to do something like this.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem here: templates don't "belong" to apps in any way other than being in their file directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that, by using `include`

```
core_app/
    templates/
        core_app/
            page1.html
contrib_app/
    templates/
        contrib_app/
            page1.html
            page2.html
```

`{% include "core_app/page1.html" %} or {% include "contrib_app/page1.html" %}`

You can also refer to this document [Template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)

Comment: to avoid name clashes, thats why used same name in `templates`

Answer (score 2):

Given you use render() shortcut in contrib.views, you just load the template from the core app and make sure the context var is satisfying what the core template renders. If you provide the path like "coreapp/template.html" the get_context() Template Loader Backend will find find the correct template given it is setup correctly:

settings.py:
Set `APP_DIRS=True` in the `TEMPLATE` dictionary. Django will lookup templates in each app via the get_template() and select_template() functions.

contrib.views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def index(request):
    ...
    template = loader.get_template('coreapp/template.html')
    context = {
        'core_template_var': core_template_var,
        ...
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Recommended reads:

render(): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

template loading: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#template-loading

Note: That you can also use a fallback template with select_template() instead of get_template(). select_template() takes a list and tries each template path in turn, returning the first that does exists.